# Bash Script for loop with nested if statement

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement

I have a script like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 x=${1:-20}

 for ((i=1;i<=x;i++))
 {
      if ((i%3==0))
      {
            echo 'Fizz'
      }
    echo $i
 }
```

I get an error color on the last brace in VIM and when I try to run the script I get a "syntax error near unexpected token" for that same brace. Without the nested if statement, this will print 1 through 20 on a new line for each number, which is the expected outcome. If the number is divisible by 3, it should print Fizz instead of that number. I'm not as worried about how to implement the replacement, that should be easy to figure out, but what I don't understand is why I cannot use a brace to close the for loop. If I take out the brace, I get an error that says end of file expected. So what is the proper syntax for ending a for loop with a nested if statement? I've looked around online and here on stack but haven't found a similar format to what I am trying to do. I don't like the

```
 for f in *
```

format as it is not as easy to read for someone coming from a different coding language and I like to keep my code looking very similar across different languages (I use comments too, but just the same, I try to keep things as similar as possible which is why I used (( )) with the for loop.)

If I comment out the if statement and leave everything else intact, the error disappears and it will print

```
 1
 Fizz
 2
 Fizz

 etc.
```

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Learn `bash` syntax instead of making something up based on other languages you know. You have unnecessary braces and are missing several keywords.

Comment: See: [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) or [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Comment: `for ((i=1;i<=x;i++)); do COMMANDS; done`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I was able to figure out thanks to @Cyrus:

```
x=${1:-20}
for ((i=1;i<=x;i++))
do
  if ((i%3==0))
  then
    echo 'Fizz'
  else
    echo $i
  fi
done
```

In many ways bash is simpler than most other languages but that makes it harder to work with when you are used to "higher" level languages.

Comment: thanks for putting the spaces in there, I have a nasty habit of forgetting them that I'm trying to break.

Answer (score 0):

So, to help out anyone else that's like me and just starting to code with bash, here is the full program I made, with comments as to why I coded it the way I did. If there are errors in my explanation or my formatting style, please point them out. Thanks! This was kind of fun to write, call me crazy.

```
# This will literally just print the string inside the single quotes on the screen
echo 'Try running this again but with something like this: fizzbuzz 25 pot kettle black'

    # The $0 is the first index, in other words the file name of the executable, 
    # this will set the default value of x to 20 but will allow the user to input 
    # something else if they want.
    x=${1:-20}

    # This is the same but with string variables
    f=${2:-FizzBuzz}
    g=${3:-Fizz}
    b=${4:-Buzz}

        # We start the index variable at 1 because it's based on the input, 
        # otherwise it would echo 0 thru 19
        for ((i=1;i<=x;1++))

               do
                   # I recommend using (( )) for if statement arithmetic operations
                   # since the syntax is similar to other programming languages
                   if ((i%3==0 && i%5==0)); then echo $f

                   # you need to use a semicolon to separate if and then if they are 
                   # on the same line, otherwise you can just go to the next line for
                   # your then statement
                   else if ((i%3==0)); then echo $g

                   else if ((i%5==0)); then echo $b

                   else echo $1

                   # You need fi in order to finish an if then statement
                   fi fi fi
              done
```